# App crashes when trying to reuse toolbar by extending custom activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-toolbar

My custom toolbar is described in `toolbar_main.xml` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And it is called from `activity_main.xml` with

```
<include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In my `MainActivity.OnCreate()` I set the toolbar as action bar and perform some operations

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo_linkshare);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Typeface ralewaySemiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-SemiBold.ttf");
Typeface ralewayItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Italic.ttf");
String text1 = "link";
String text2 = "share";
Spannable s = new SpannableString(text1+text2);
s.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(ralewaySemiBold), 0, text1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(ralewayItalic), text1.length(), text1.length()+text2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
TextView lettering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
lettering.setText(s);
```

And as I have a custom menu for `MainActivity` (which is different from the menu I want to use in other Activities) I do the following

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            [...]


        }
}
```

Since I want to show this toolbar (with the logo and custom title) in all my Activities (but handling the menu separately) I thought about creating a custom Activity and subsequently extend it wherever I need it.

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo_linkshare);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Typeface ralewaySemiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-SemiBold.ttf");
        Typeface ralewayItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Italic.ttf");

        String text1 = "link";
        String text2 = "share";

        Spannable s = new SpannableString(text1+text2);
        s.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(ralewaySemiBold), 0, text1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        s.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(ralewayItalic), text1.length(), text1.length()+text2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        TextView lettering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        lettering.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Basically moving the setup code from `MainActivity` and instead extending it

`public class MainActivity extends MenuActivity`

This much results in a crash as soon as I launch the app, with no errors or warnings in the logcat

Am I doing something which is not as it should be?

--Edit1--

I found out that if I add

```
<include
layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

to `activity_menu-xml` i.e.: the xml of `MenuActivity`, the app doesn't crash, but an empty toolbar is shown

--Edit2--

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.dima.polimi.massimobortolamei.linkshare, PID: 17736
 Theme: themes:{}
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dima.polimi.massimobortolamei.linkshare/com.dima.polimi.massimobortolamei.linkshare.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
     at com.dima.polimi.massimobortolamei.linkshare.activities.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:23)
     at com.dima.polimi.massimobortolamei.linkshare.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat from the crash?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors in the Logcat ! it just crashes! please see the edit

Comment: If the app crashes, there should be a logcat. Check your filters

Comment: Yes...i'm stupid, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to give the Toolbar inclusion an ID.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And you seem to be missing the Toolbar setup in the `MenuActivity`, which explains the `NullPointerException`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

// Find the view from the toolbar
TextView lettering = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
```

Note: a good idea would be to make a `protected void setupToolbar()` method, then you can hide that away from the `MainActivity` through inheritance.

```
public abstract class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutRes());
        setupToolbar();
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutRes();

    protected void setupToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find the view from the toolbar
        TextView lettering = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo_linkshare);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Typeface ralewaySemiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-SemiBold.ttf");
        Typeface ralewayItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Italic.ttf");

        String text1 = "link";
        String text2 = "share";

        Spannable s = new SpannableString(text1+text2);
        s.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(ralewaySemiBold), 0, text1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        s.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(ralewayItalic), text1.length(), text1.length()+text2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        lettering.setText(s);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends ToolbarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override 
    protected int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
```

Comment: I already have an id for the toolbar where it is declared in `toolbar_main.xml`, should i give an inclusion id nonetheless ? I added the Toolbar setup in `MenuActivity` , but same error. Should i include the toolbar in `activity_menu` as well?

Comment: Duplicating the ID doesn't hurt. General rule: Whatever `setContentView` is using needs the Toolbar

Comment: Ok, i have duplicated the id and included the toolbar in `MenuActivity`'s layout as well. The app doesn't crash anymore but now the toolbar is empty

Comment: Well, `getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo_linkshare);` should at least show a logo.

Comment: I know right? It feels like i am missing something. Should i do something in the `MainActivity` like setting up the toolbar again?

Comment: You need to setup the toolbar again if you are calling `setContentView` in both the `MenuActivity` and `MainActivity`, yes, because it's actually a different toolbar, which is why I suggested the `protected` method.

Comment: But i am doing all this in order to setup the toolbar only once, and then use it in every activity ! i don't want two different toolbars, i'm so confused. Where should i put the protected method?

Comment: You can't setup only once and use two different layout files. `activity_menu.xml` is pointless, really, if you're going to immediately overwrite it. See my updated answer, please.

Comment: Yes it works! I see your point about activity_menu.xml, but it has been automatically created. Isn't this the common practice to reuse the toolbar in every activity? Just create an activity setup the toolbar and extend it.

Comment: If you want to always have a Toolbar, then you should open the `styles.xml` and use the Theme that comes with one

Comment: I'll do more research about this then! it seems i have misunderstood something. Thank you very much for everything!

Comment: tried lots of things and this was the only approach that worked for me